# C# - Passing values in an edit to XtraReport (DevExpress)

Tags: c#, report

I have a XtraReport (DevExpress) in the project, I'm trying to pass a value entered in the editbox (form1) to report the RichBox. How can I do this?

I'm not using any dataset, and only an empty report with some richtextbox.

Comment: Could you show us your code and what you have tried? Are you getting a compile error? Is your code throwing an exception at runtime? Is it running but just not updating the box?

Comment: Already solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
In the tab properties , change the value: xrRichText1 Modifiers = Public

```
            XtraReport1 test = new XtraReport1();
            test.xrRichText1.Text = "testing";

            //Show Preview
            using (ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(test))
            {
                printTool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
                printTool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog(UserLookAndFeel.Default);
            }
```